# APK 64 Bit Compatibility

Tags: java, android, google-play, apk, 64-bit

I have an Android app that is published in Google Play. How can I check if it is 64-bit compliant?

I can not see any .so files but where to look?

> If you do not have any .so files in your APK, you are already 64-bit
>   compliant.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

[image: Apk Analyzer]

Where to look? res folder? META-INF? third_party? or elsewhere?

As you see, there is no .so files but I do not know where to look.

As a result is my app 64-bit compliant?

I am using some libraries in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to worry about 64-bit compatibility if you use native (C) code. This gets compiled as an .so file - if you do not have any native code and only use Java/Kotlin, then your code is already 64-bit compliant.

From your screenshot, you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for response but I am using more than 10 libraries and I do not know if they use native code or not.

Comment: .so are in the lib folder; you don't have that folder, so you don't have native code.